# Как в вордпресс вывести текст с вхождением запроса при поиске?

Tags: wordpress

В вордпресс при поиске выводится анонс записи, в которой есть поисковый запрос.
Можно ли как-то выводить не анонс записи, а часть текста, в которую входит
поисковый запрос?

Comment: А что такое часть текста? Это 200 символов до прижайшей точки от поискового вхождения? И после? Тогда нужно средставми php прочитать весь content, найти подрезать и вывести.

Comment: Да, именно так. Только как это средствами PHP можно сделать?

Comment: Не проще ли готовым решением воспользоваться?

Comment: А есть какое-то готовое решение? Стандартный поиск не позволяет реализовать так, как нужно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Темы WordPress обычно выводят результаты поиска с помощью шаблона search.php. В стандартной теме twentysixteen этот шаблон
\wp-content\themes\twentysixteen\search.php
вызывает еще и
\wp-content\themes\twentysixteen\template-parts\content-search.php

Можно отредактировать этот шаблон в той части, где вызывается функция excerpt и поставить туда свой код, который получает содержимое поста и делает с ним то, что нужно. Поисковый запрос в коде шаблона можно получить так:

```
$search = $_GET['s'];
```

В других темах это работает аналогично.